# jQuery AJAX on a Windows Phone

Tags: jquery, ajax, windows-mobile

So I'm trying to do a page with infinite scroll functionality. What I've got works great in all browsers/phones, EXCEPT for IE on a Windows phone.

There are 2 problems... the first is that the function isn't called on page load. I'm using:

```
$(document).ready (
    GetRecords()
);
```

The next issue is that I don't get anything from the AJAX:

```
function GetRecords() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "loadmore.php?from="+intNumDisplayed+"&get=20",
        success: function(strResponse) {
            if (strResponse.length>0) {
                $("#forumtable").append(strResponse);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I can see, using alerts in different places, that the GetRecords function is being called, but I never get any results.

As ever, thanks for your help!

Comment: When you put an error property on your .ajax call what do you get?

Comment: Nothing - it doesn't return an error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note to self - always make sure you have the latest jQuery!

I was using 1.7.2 - when I updated everything worked...